# Override 'OR' and 'AND' functions

Tags: php, function, overriding

I'm writing a class where I need to have an OR and an AND function declared. If I declare it the normal way i get the following error message:

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' in /Users/... on line 53
```

What's the correct way to achieve this in php? (Callable OR and AND functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't support operator overloading so you can't do that.